# Modifying a function to approximate to expirimental data

Tags: calculus, functions

I am having trouble about modifying a function. We have a function that is believed to define a physical condition truly. However, according to my experiments the given function is insufficient. I want to modify the function in a way that it approximately fits to the experimental data. The original function is $$\sigma = {R\over\sqrt{ I\cos(\gamma)}}$$ The figure below shows original function as dashed line and experimental data as continuous line.

[image: Original function is shown by dashed line. Experimental data is shown by solid line]

Original function is shown by dashed line. Experimental data is shown by solid line

Dividing the function with a scalar approximates to experimental data but beginning of lines does not overlap in this case. Could you please tell me how can I modify the function using $I$ variable, where $I$ shows decreasing trend? 
I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $\sigma,R,\gamma$? Variables? Constants? If variables, how do they vary? Also, what's the $x,y$ axis in the graph?

Comment: Sorry for missing information. All of them are variables. Sigma is computed as a function of R cos(gamma) and I. R is positive real number increasing. Gamma is constant for this case and I is decreasing from 150 to 80. x axis is R and y axis is sigma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given data looks insufficient to get the job done; as OP mentioned, counted $\cos\gamma$ as a constant, and I didn't think into how to control the equation with $I$ alone; here's a way to control it with $R$.

My take on it:

`R  σ       M=I*cos(γ)      σ~      M~=I*cos(γ)     n=M~/M

20  1.65    146.9237833     0.5     1600            10.89
40  3.6     123.4567901     0.9     1975.308642     16
60  5.7     110.8033241     1.5     1600            14.44
80  8.3     92.90172739     2.5     1024            11.0224
100 11      82.6446281      4       625 7.5625      0.075625`

Where $\sigma$, $M$ are approx values obtained/computed from "dotted" line graph, $\sigma$~, $M$~ are from OP's "thick line" graph (Approx).

Now, I [approximated](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approximate+10.9%2C16%2C14.44%2C11.0224%2C7.5625+...+) variable "n" (used cubic approximation by alpha) to say $f(x)$    such that $f(1)=10.89,....$

Easiest way to get $1,2,3,...$ here is $\frac R{20}$.

So I becomes $\frac{M\text{~}}{f\left(\frac R{20}\right)}$, where $M$~ is OP's $I\times\cos\gamma$.

So the equation becomes $\sigma\text^=\dfrac{R\sqrt{f(\frac R{20})}}{\sqrt{I\cos\gamma}}$

`R  Apprx n     I^=M~/Apprx         σ^

20  10.94267    146.2165998     1.653985339
40  15.82931    124.7880446     3.580745886
60  14.69603    108.8729405     5.750310209
80  10.85171    94.36300823     8.235483441
100 7.60523     82.18028909     11.03103259`

Graph:

[image: Approximation]

Where blue line is your "dotted line" (original) graph; "dotted line" yellow is new $\sigma\text^$, orange is the experimental graph (all approximate).

Now, following the same procedure, with more exact values and knowledge of $\cos\gamma$,  I hope that you can get a neater approximation function.

Concluding:

1. Using original values; calculate $n_i=\frac{I_{yours}}{I_{orig}}$
2. Approximate list of $n$ with some function which best fits; say $f(x):f(1)=n_1,...$ (may the [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) be with you)
3. Replace $I$ by $\frac I{n_{approx}}=\frac I{f(\frac R{20})}$ in equation obtaining $\sigma\text^=\dfrac{R\sqrt{f(\frac R{20})}}{\sqrt{I\cos\gamma}}$

Comment: Note: Sleepy head, its past 12AM here! Bound to contain errors; please be nice to point it out if you find any!

Comment: Dear Jesse P Francis thank you very much for help